# Largest bifocal triangle in an ellipse

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

Ellipse $E$ has foci at $P$ and $Q$, and semi-major and semi-minor axes of length $a$ and $b$, respectively.

**Find the area of the largest triangle that can be (parttially) inscribed in ellipse $E$, such that one of the vertices is at $P$, the opposite side passes through $Q$, and the two vertices not at $P$ are on the ellipse.**

Such triangles have nice properties when the ellipse is considered as a curved reflective surface; for example, if you sent a ray of light from $P$ along one leg of the triangle, the path of the light will be a "figure 8" starting from that triangle, then tracing a triangle on the other side of $P$, and possibly, when the area is maximal, repeating itself.  But I have not been able to prove this.

Extra kudos if somebody can solve this by some geometric argument, without brute-forcing by analytic geometry and calculus.

Comment: Hi Mark: I got a solution "without brute-forcing" as you ask. Tomorrow will post (when drafted in English). Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates relative to $Q$, $$r(\theta)=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-e\cos \theta}=\frac{b^2}{a-c\cos \theta}$$

where $\, \displaystyle c=ae=\frac{1}{2} PQ \,$ and 
$\, \displaystyle e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$.

For $\, 0< \theta <\pi \,$, we have

\begin{align*}
  \Delta &=
   \frac{PQ\sin \theta}{2}
    \left[
      \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-e\cos \theta}+\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos \theta}
    \right] \\
  &= \frac{2a^2 e(1-e^2)\sin \theta}{1-e^2 \cos^2 \theta} \\
  \frac{d\Delta}{d\theta} &=
  \frac{2a^2e(1-e^2)\cos \theta (e^2 \sin^2 \theta+e^2-1)}
       {(1-e^2 \cos^2 \theta)^2} \\
\end{align*}

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{d\Delta}{d\theta}=0 \,$ when 
$\, \cos \theta =0 \,$ or 
$\displaystyle \, \sin \theta=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{e} \, , \;
e> \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$.

The maximal area occurs when

$$\theta=
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccl}
    \frac{\pi}{2} & , & 0<e \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \\
    \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{e} &, & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}<e<1
   \end{array}
\right.$$

that is

$$\Delta=
\left \{
  \begin{array}{ccl}
    \frac{2bc^2}{a} & , & 0<e \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \\
    ab &, & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}<e<1
   \end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: Nice. The use of polar coordinates on $Q$ is the key; it works much simpler than using polar coordinates on the center of the ellipse.  I'm waiting for Piquito's solution to be posted today, before checking this off as "the" solution; meanwhile I give it a thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, well, once again I lose the scoop by not master English prose. I give you below my answer before it is finish.

A straight line passing through the foci Q, cuts the ellipse in two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. **One realizes that the problem reduces just to determining the maximum of the sum
$y_1+y_2$** (*This sum is easily get from the coefficient of $y$ in the respective quadratic resolvent in $y$*) **because all of the concerned triangles have an area which is the sum of the areas of two triangles having a constant base**.

This base has a length equal to the length of the segment $\overline{PQ}=2c$ where $(c,0)$ is the foci $Q$ to the right of $P$. 
One has $$c^2=a^2-b^2\iff \frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{(\frac{b^2}{a})^2}{b^2}= 1$$ It follows  the point $(c,y)\in E$ corresponds to the two coordinates $y=\pm \frac{b^2}{a}$ in the ellipse $E$ of equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. Hence the triangle of vertices $(-c,0),(c,\frac{b^2}{a}),(c,-\frac{b^2}{a})$ has area $$A=\frac{2c\cdot 2b^2}{2a}=\frac{2cb^2}{a}$$ This triangle is a main candidate to be the required maximal one. I stop here.  I suppose the answer of the friend Ng Chung Tak is correct.

[image]

Comment: Take $x=ny-c$, we get $(a^2+b^2 n^2)y^2-2b^2 cny-b^4=0 \implies y_{1} y_{2}<0$, we should maximize $|y_{1}-y_{2}|$, or equivalently its square $(y_{1}+y_{2})^{2}-4y_{1}y_{2}$.  The rest of work is still tedious.

Comment: You have to find the maximun of just the coefficient of $y$ in your equation after it becomes monic dividing by $(a^2+b^2n^2)$

Comment: Don't forget $\Delta=c(|y_{1}|+|y_{2}|)$ where $y_{1},y_{2}$ are **opposite in signs**.  So $\Delta=c|y_{1}-y_{2}|$.

Comment: For example when $n=0$, $a^2 y^2-b^4=0$, so $y_{1}+y_{2}=0$ and $y_{1} y_{2}=-b^4/a^2$, hence $(y_{1}-y_{2})^2=4b^4/a^2$ which gives $\Delta=2b^2c/a$

Comment: Yes, obviously. I have seen this as a deficiency in the details in my incomplete answer but I let it go. The main idea (useful, I guess) is that the required maximun is just concerned with $y_1$ and $y_2$.